# How can I populate a string array with a parameter method C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, parameters

I am trying to populate a string array called "items" with a pre written method called "insert".

The project has pre written code "b.insert("apple");" etc etc and the method given is "public void insert(T item)". I have to write the code in this method to make the "insert" function work. I have to pass "item" into "items" array but my for loop simply gives me the output "milk" 10 times. Because of this, I know that "item" value is simply changing to the last string passed in the insert method. Would I have to write a nested for loop where "item" is a counter? In this case "item" cannot be a counter because it is a string type. Should I convert "item" into an array?
 I'm not sure why such a seemingly simple task has me stumped by I've been at it for hours and at this point I just want to sort it out for the sake of sanity.

thanks in advance

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BoundedBag<string> b = new BoundedBag<string>("ShoppingList", 10);
        b.insert("apple");
        b.insert("eggs");
        b.insert("milk");
        Console.WriteLine(b);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
public interface Bag<T> where T : class
{
    void insert(T item);
    string getName();
    bool isEmpty();
}
public class BoundedBag<T> : Bag<T> where T : class
{
    private string bagName; // the name of the bag
    protected int size; // max size of the bag
    private int lastIndex;
    protected T[] items;

    public BoundedBag(string name, int size)
    {
        bagName = name;
        this.size = size;
        rnd = new Random();
        items = new T[size];
    }
    public string getName()
    {
        return bagName;
    }
    public bool isEmpty()
    {
        return lastIndex == -1;
    }
   public bool isFull()
    {
        if(items.Length  >= size)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else { return false;}
    }

    public void insert(T item)
    {
        // fill in the code as directed below:
        // insert item into items container
        // throws FullBagException if necessary

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            items[i] = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to refine that long winded ramble into a concise problem statement and ask a succinct question after you read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: cool thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

You only want to insert one item into your array on insert so you shouldn't have a loop at all. Use the lastIndex field to insert one item into the appropriate place in the array:

```
public void insert(T item)
{
    // fill in the code as directed below:
    // insert item into items container
    // throws FullBagException if necessary

    if(isFull())
    {
       throw new FullBagException();
    }

    items[++lastIndex] = item;
}
```

Unfortunately your isFull method is also broken and your isEmpty method won't work properly unless you change the constructor.

```
public BoundedBag(string name, int size)
{
     bagName = name;
     this.size = size;
     items = new T[size];
     lastIndex = -1;
}

public bool isFull()
{
    return lastIndex == size - 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, wish I could upvote you.

    items[++lastIndex] = item;  is what i needed to make this work. Before working with loops I was attempting  something similar but you made use of lastIndex which is what I completely ignored. thanks again for your help